# python selenium search query provides multiple results. how choose which is mine search query?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made a search query with selenium. after that i get multiple results. Now the problem is, only one link is right.how can i select the link from multiple results?  and parse the data from the results.
i have a list and every time a search query is made results may change sometimes its 10 or 15.

the following code will select the first result always, But in this case i am looking for 4 link:

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
#time.sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element_by_name("p_name")
#time.sleep(1)
username.send_keys("xxxxx)
#username.clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[6]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a").click()

html = driver.page_source

soup =BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.find_all('table'):
    print tag.text
```

Comment: Are you saying that  `soup.find_all('table')` is printing multiple `tag.texts`?

Comment: No, what i'm trying to say is `username.send_keys"xxx"` give me multiple results.how can selenium select the right result to get further information. @TimothyCope

Comment: When you do the search manually, how do you know which link to click in your search results?  Perhaps you need to find a way to enhance your search query on the site so that you only get one result to click.

Comment: when i do search query manually i just  check for correct words `like OREGON BUD COMPANY, LLC  =OREGON BUD COMPANY, LLC. In Search results there may be OREGON BUDS ,LLC (which is not my link) . this is how i find my reult link. @BreaksSoftware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("OREGON BUD COMPANY LLC")
```

instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"OREGON BUD COMPANY LLC")]/../..').text
```

This will follow the exact match and will get you to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You know the general form of entries in the search results page, that is, they're capitalised and shorn of special characters. Assuming that you have such a search page you can use this knowledge and `selenium` to search for text containing what you want, in this way, with an xpath expression.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://egov.sos.state.or.us/br/pkg_web_name_srch_inq.do_name_srch?p_name=OREGON%20BUD%20COMPANY%2C%20LLC&p_regist_nbr=&p_srch=PHASE1&p_print=FALSE&p_entity_status=ACTINA')
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"OREGON BUD COMPANY LLC")]/../..').text
'   4 DLLC ACT 1097010-94   CUR   OREGON BUD COMPANY LLC Search'
```

I've simply dumped the text for the entire row. You'll need to extract the text items you actually want from the parent `tr` element.

PS: There's a good page of xpath expressions at https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use better selectors that only return one result. I prefer CSS Selectors but the process is largely the same for XPath if you prefer.

To get a CSS Selector in Chrome:

1. Right-click on the element and select 'Inspect'
2. Right-click on the element in the DOM explorer of DevTools
3. Select "Copy" > "Copy selector" (Alternatively you could get the XPath here too)

   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(("body > form > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type='text']")).sendKeys("Timothy")

   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(("body > form > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > input[type='text']")).sendKeys("Cope")

Comment: well, In that case i have a long list of queries. every time i can't change key value.is there any other way?  @TimothyCope

Comment: Typically the find element logic/queries are stored in a POM (PageObjectModel), if that is what you are getting at.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the implementation in Python, but here is the [official guide](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) from Selenium.